# Jquery dropdown select issue in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

The following code works in Firefox but not in Chrome and IE. Any idea why? Thanks!

```
$('#image_dd option:selected').live('click', function() {

    alert("TEST 1");

    if ($("#image_dd").val().length) {
          alert("TEST 2");
    }

    return false;

});
```

Comment: @JasCav It's not triggering any of the alerts i've placed for testing.

Comment: I dont think its related but that `return false;` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE doesn't pick up "click" for select options (although firefox does!).
You will probably need to use  the "change" event instead, works fine in ie, chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I think your trying to bind to the wrong element and event. Try binding your event handler to the select element and using the "change" or "blur" triggers.